# Sidr: WIndows Phone Issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, flip

I'm having some issues with the [Sidr plugin](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) on Windows Phone's running both IE9 and IE10.

When the user clicks the menu button, the entire page is pushed off the right hand side of the screen, including the sidr menu.

I've only been able to replicate this error on a Windows Phone at the moment. The plugin works on every other mobile browser I've tested so far.

Any help would be massively appreciated in solving this issue. Thanks!

Image of the issue:

> [image]

Comment: Have you been able to test this on an actual device, or only in the emulator?

Comment: I've tested it on the device as well yea, but I only have the emulator on hand at the moment.

Comment: I was hoping the problem is only on the emulator.

Comment: Yea, it's a bit of a nightmare to be honest. It's a great plugin, so it's a shame it falls over a little bit on Windows Phone. Any ideas how to fix it?